# To do RegEx, what are the advantages/disadvantages to use UTF-8 string instead of unicode?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, utf-8

Usually, the best practice in python, when using international languages, is to use unicode and to convert early any input to unicode and to convert late to a string encoding (UTF-8 most of the times).

But when I need to do RegEx on unicode I don't find the process really friendly. For example, if I need to find the 'é' character follow by one ore more spaces I have to write (Note: my shell or python file are set to UTF-8):

```
re.match('(?u)\xe9\s+', unicode)
```

So I have to write the unicode code of 'é'. That's not really convenient and if I need to built the RegEx from a variable, things start to come ugly. Example:

```
word_to_match = 'Élisa™'.decode('utf-8') # that return a unicode object
regex = '(?u)%s\s+' % word_to_match
re.match(regex, unicode)
```

And this is a simple example. So if you have a lot of Regexs to do one after another with special characters in it, I found more easy and natural to do the RegEx on a string encoded in UTF-8. Example:

```
re.match('Élisa\s+', string)
re.match('Geneviève\s+', string)
re.match('DrØshtit\s+', string)
```

Is there's something I'm missing ? What are the drawbacks of the UTF-8 approach ?

### UPDATE

Ok, I find the problem. I was doing my tests in ipython but unfortunately it seems to mess the encoding. Example:

In the python shell

```
>>> string_utf8 = 'Test « with theses » quotes Éléments'
>>> string_utf8
'Test \xc2\xab with theses \xc2\xbb quotes \xc3\x89l\xc3\xa9ments'
>>> print string_utf8
Test « with theses » quotes Éléments
>>>
>>> unicode_string = u'Test « with theses » quotes Éléments'
>>> unicode_string
u'Test \xab with theses \xbb quotes \xc9l\xe9ments'
>>> print unicode_string
Test « with theses » quotes Éléments
>>>
>>> unicode_decoded_from_utf8 = string_utf8.decode('utf-8')
>>> unicode_decoded_from_utf8
u'Test \xab with theses \xbb quotes \xc9l\xe9ments'
>>> print unicode_decoded_from_utf8
Test « with theses » quotes Éléments
```

In ipython

```
In [1]: string_utf8 = 'Test « with theses » quotes Éléments'

In [2]: string_utf8
Out[2]: 'Test \xc2\xab with theses \xc2\xbb quotes \xc3\x89l\xc3\xa9ments'

In [3]: print string_utf8
Test « with theses » quotes Éléments

In [4]: unicode_string = u'Test « with theses » quotes Éléments'

In [5]: unicode_string
Out[5]: u'Test \xc2\xab with theses \xc2\xbb quotes \xc3\x89l\xc3\xa9ments'

In [6]: print unicode_string
Test Â« with theses Â» quotes ÃlÃ©ments

In [7]: unicode_decoded_from_utf8 = string_utf8.decode('utf-8')

In [8]: unicode_decoded_from_utf8
Out[8]: u'Test \xab with theses \xbb quotes \xc9l\xe9ments'

In [9]: print unicode_decoded_from_utf8
Test « with theses » quotes Éléments
```

As you can see, ipython is messing with encoding when using the u'' notation. That was the source of my problems. The bug is mentionned here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ipython/+bug/339642

Comment: UTF8 is an encoding of Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Python 2.x? If so, it's generally considered rather bad form to leave your non-ASCII characters in byte strings. Just use Unicode strings the whole way through:

```
re.match(u'Élisa™\\s+', unicodestring)
```

It may look a bit funny writing ‘u’ at the start of your string literals, but that goes away in Python 3.x, and it's really not that bad.

Matching UTF-8 strings with regex works for a limited subset of expressions. But if you want to use case-insensitive matches, or non-ASCII characters in a `[group]`, or length-sensitive expressions, it'll go wrong. Best stick with Unicode.

(You probably don't especially need the `(?u)` if you are only using `\s`, that only brings in some of the more unusual spaces that you may not want to match anyway. Useful for case-insensitive matching on Unicode strings though.)

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that I was using python 2.x. That's what I did at first but it didn't work. But I just found why: I was doing my tests in ipython and it seems to mess with encoding and decoding. I added some info at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Ah, yeah... pushing unencoded non-ASCII characters through the console is always a bit dodgy, unfortunately, especially on Windows. Should be fine in your scripts with the encoding line at the top though.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using utf-8 in your python source, you can just write:

```
u'Élisa'
```

and that would be a unicode string, equivalent to writing:

```
u'\xc9lisa'
```

So the 'u' prefix makes the decode thing unneeded. If you leave out the 'u' and write:

```
'Élisa'
```

Then you'd have a (utf-8 encoded) bytestring, equivalent to:

```
'\xc3\x89lisa'
```

Comment: That's what I did at first but it didn't work. But I just found why: I was doing my tests in ipython and it seems to mess with encoding and decoding. I added some info at the bottom of my question.